# Call function from within tkinter button

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to ask how to change the following code so that the animation.FuncAnimation() command is called within one of the button clicks (doesn't matter which one) while still keeping the functionality of switching to a new page. The code is taken from the python programming tutorial (sentdex) on placing a live matplotlib graph within a tkinter gui.

I tried a few ways such as placing the function call within the button declaration, making a new function containing the function for showing the frame and starting the animation and calling that from the button. I've failed a few times and would appreciate suggestions. Thank you in advance.

```
    import matplotlib matplotlib.use("TkAgg") 
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg 
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
    import matplotlib.animation as animation 
    from matplotlib import style 
    import tkinter as tk 
    from tkinter import ttk 

    LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12) 
    style.use("ggplot") 
    f=Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100) 
    a = f.add_subplot(111) 

    def animate(i): 
        pullData = open("sampleData.txt","r").read() 
        dataList = pullData.split('\n') 
        xList = [] 
        yList = [] 
        for eachLine in dataList: 
            if len(eachLine)>1: 
                x,y = eachLine.split(',') 
                xList.append(int(x)) 
                yList.append(int(y)) 
                a.clear() 
                a.plot(xList,yList) 

    class SeaofBTCapp (tk.Tk): 

        def _init_(self,*args,**kwargs): 

            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
            tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="icon.ico") 
            tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC client") 
            container = tk.Frame(self) 
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True) 
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
            self.frames = {} 

            for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree): 
                frame = F(container, self) 
                self.frames[F] = frame 
                frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(StartPage) 

         def show_frame(self,cont): 
             frame = self.frames[cont] 
             frame.tkraise() 

         def qf(): 
             print("Hamne kar dikhaya") 

    class StartPage(tk.Frame): 

        def _init_(self, parent, controller):

            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
            label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) 
            button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(PageOne)) 
            button.pack() 
            buttona = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(PageTwo)) 
            buttona.pack() 
            buttonb = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Graph Page", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(PageThree)) 
            buttonb.pack() 

    class PageOne(tk.Frame): 

        def _init_(self, parent, controller): 

            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT) 
            label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(StartPage))
            button1.pack() 

    class PageTwo(tk.Frame): 

        def _init_(self, parent, controller): 

            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two", font=LARGE_FONT) label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) 
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(StartPage)) 
            button1.pack() 

    class PageThree(tk.Frame): 

        def _init_(self, parent, controller):

            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent) 
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page", font=LARGE_FONT) label.pack(pady=10, padx=10) 
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda :controller.show_frame(StartPage)) 
            button1.pack() 
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,self) 
            canvas.show() 
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) 

            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self) 
            toolbar.update() 
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    app= SeaofBTCapp() 
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f,animate, interval=1000) 
    app.mainloop()﻿
```

Comment: create a custom function. Tie that function to the button. In that function, call the other function and switch the page.

Comment: The thing about animation function is that you need to keep a reference to it.

Comment: You've posted a lot of irrelevant code. For example, do we really need four pages to duplicate this problem? Please consider condensing the code down to a [mcve]